If a default value for a class attribute is set to a result to a function call, why doesn't the function get called for each new class instance?
Minimum reproducible example:
import uuid
from typing import NamedTuple

def get_uuid():
    return str(uuid.uuid4())

class User(NamedTuple):
    id: str = get_uuid()
    email: str = ""

Executing the above code yields:
>>> user1 = User(email="user@usertopia.com")
>>> user1.id
'9258bb4e-ef69-44fc-b01e-7d083b9fde50'
>>> user2 = User(email="user2@usertopia.com")
>>> user2.id
'9258bb4e-ef69-44fc-b01e-7d083b9fde50'

I did not expect this. Rather, I thought that user1 and user2 would have different ids.
Why does this happen? How do I make sure that get_uuid() is called for each new User instance?

You'll want an instance attribute rather than a class attribute, if you expect unique values per instance. You might also want to check the email of both

The body of a class statement is evaluated immediately, then used to create the type, unlike the body of a def statement, which is only evaluated when the resulting function is called.

(typing.NamedTuple is a bit of a mess to explain clearly, though, since it's not actually a type, but a function that's been engineered to be allowed as a base class.)

I'd been inclined to do this as a dataclass, which can have a default factory: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=b41cb3b86bad3a964f4c7382bda54bb0
